# Laravek Excel "Call to a member function setWorksheet() on array" when export multiple drawing

Tags: laravel, drawing, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I have export single image successfully. but I cant export multiple image. How to export multiple images in laravel excel ?

i get this error "Call to a member function setWorksheet() on array"   using laravel excel maatwebsite-excel

```
public function drawings()
   {
       $Pengaduan = Pengaduan::select(
           'pengaduanTiket',
           'nama_lengkap',
           'no_hp',
           'no_kk',
           'no_ktp',
           'alamat_sesuai_ktp',
           'nama_pengaduan',
           'jenis_pengaduan',
           'isi_pengaduan',
           'status',
           'keterangan',
           'dokumen_pendukung',
           'dokumentasi',
           'lampiran',
       )->whereBetween('created_at', [$this->requestawal, $this->requestakhir])->get();


       $image1 = [];
       $image2 = [];
       $image3 = [];
       $rowNum = 2;
       foreach ($Pengaduan as $row) {

           $file1 = new Drawing();
           if ($row->dokumen_pendukung == null || $row->dokumen_pendukung == "") {
               $file1->setPath(public_path('/assets/images/default.jpg'));
           } else {
               $file1->setPath(public_path('/assets/uploads/images/pengaduan/') . $row->dokumen_pendukung);
           }
           $file1->setheight(20);
           $file1->setCoordinates('L' . $rowNum); 
           $image1[] = $file1;


           $file2 = new Drawing();
           if ($row->dokumentasi == null || $row->dokumentasi == "") {
               $file2->setPath(public_path('/assets/images/default.jpg'));
           } else {
               $file2->setPath(public_path('/assets/uploads/images/pengaduan/') . $row->dokumentasi);
           }
           $file2->setheight(20);
           $file2->setCoordinates('M' . $rowNum); 
           $image2[] = $file2;


           $file3 = new Drawing();
           if ($row->lampiran == null || $row->lampiran == "") {
               $file3->setPath(public_path('/assets/images/default.jpg'));
           } else {
               $file3->setPath(public_path('/assets/uploads/images/pengaduan/') . $row->lampiran);
           }
           $file3->setheight(20);
           $file3->setCoordinates('N' . $rowNum); 
           $image3[] = $file3;


           $rowNum++;
       }
       
       return [$image1, $image2, $image3];
   }
```

please help,

#It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: This doesn't look like laravel-excel's syntax according to the [docs](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
//...
return [...$image1, ...$image2, ...$image3];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function drawings()
    {
        $Pengaduan = Pengaduan::select(
            'pengaduanTiket',
            'nama_lengkap',
            'no_hp',
            'no_kk',
            'no_ktp',
            'alamat_sesuai_ktp',
            'nama_pengaduan',
            'jenis_pengaduan',
            'isi_pengaduan',
            'status',
            'keterangan',
            'dokumen_pendukung',
            'dokumentasi',
            'lampiran',
        )->whereBetween('created_at', [$this->requestawal, $this->requestakhir])->get();


        $gambar = [];
        $rowNum = 2;
        foreach ($Pengaduan as $row) {

            $file1 = new Drawing();
            if ($row->dokumen_pendukung == null || $row->dokumen_pendukung == "") {
                $file1->setPath(public_path('/assets/images/default.jpg'));
            } else {
                $file1->setPath(public_path('/assets/uploads/images/pengaduan/') . $row->dokumen_pendukung);
            }
            $file1->setheight(30);
            $file1->setCoordinates('L' . $rowNum);
            $gambar[] = $file1;


            $file2 = new Drawing();
            if ($row->dokumentasi == null || $row->dokumentasi == "") {
                $file2->setPath(public_path('/assets/images/default.jpg'));
            } else {
                $file2->setPath(public_path('/assets/uploads/images/pengaduan/') . $row->dokumentasi);
            }
            $file2->setheight(30);
            $file2->setCoordinates('M' . $rowNum);
            $gambar[] = $file2;


            $file3 = new Drawing();
            if ($row->lampiran == null || $row->lampiran == "") {
                $file3->setPath(public_path('/assets/images/default.jpg'));
            } else {
                $file3->setPath(public_path('/assets/uploads/images/pengaduan/') . $row->lampiran);
            }
            $file3->setheight(30);
            $file3->setCoordinates('N' . $rowNum);
            $gambar[] = $file3;


            $rowNum++;
        }

        return ($gambar);
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).